# Не выводится текст из лога на экран

Tags: c++

Так как нельзя с одной программы вызывать 2 консоли, я написал в game.exe сохранение лога в файл, а log.exe должен считывать и выводить текст из лога на экран. В game.exe все отлично работает. Проблема в считывании. т.е. log.exe не выводит на экран ничего. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно на скриншоте, изменение произошло(я нажал D).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 В файл записалось "RIGHT CALLED".
Но в консоли ничего нет.
log.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool exit_=0;
    string x, previousX;
    ifstream bob("log.txt");
    while (!exit_) {
        bob >> x;
        if (x == "EXIT CALLED") { exit_ = 1; }
        if (x == previousX) { continue; }
        cout << x;
        previousX = x;
        Sleep(50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как минимум у вас никогда не сработает `x == "EXIT CALLED"`, потому как `bob>>x;` читает по одному слову... А вы для начала проверьте состояние файла (открыт ли - может, он в это время другой программой эксклюзивно открыт, не выставлен ли бит сбоя...)

Comment: Как тогда считывать полностью строку при помощи  ifstream?

Comment: `getline` - см. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Исправил. Через bob.is_open() проверил, открыт ли файл. Все отлично работает, кроме вывода в консоль.

Comment: На всякий случай - WinApi позволяет открывать больше одного консольного окна.

Comment: Вы уверены, что барахлит именно чтение из лога, а не запись в лог? Скорее дело именно в записи: файл, уже открытий на чтение, не удается открыть на запись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что Вы имеете файл в том состоянии, в каком он был при запуске `log.exe`. Попробуйте перенести открытие файла в тело цикла, не забыв в его конце закрыть файл. Тогда все должно заработать.

Comment: Благодарю. Всё заработало.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)